# Windspeed and Aeroplanes

Tags: kinematics, momentum, velocity, aircraft

Say we had an airplane cruising at velocity $V$ and the airplane was going from point $A$ to $B$. If the wind was also blowing in the same direction from  $A$ to $B$, at a velocity $U$, could we say the aircraft is moving at a velocity of $U + V$?

If so, could someone please explain it to me in terms of
forces and changes in momentum?

I've been stuck on this for a while now and can't come to a conclusion as to *why* the *wind's velocity* can be treated in the same way as the *plane's velocity*.

Comment: is this a homework question or is it in general? (if it's like from a book, It would be useful to know the title (`if there is one`))    **edit: thanks for replying**

Comment: Just a general question

Comment: I've adapted it from something I was asked in the past

Comment: Velocities are always relative - you have to specify what you're treating as *stationary* in order for this question to make sense. Obviously the aircraft can't be moving *both* at velocity $V$ and at velocity $U+V$ for the same meaning of "velocity".

Comment: The earth is what we are comparing the velocities to

Comment: @navop the "earth"?  the.. spin of the planet or .. ? sorry I don't follow at all (or I am missing something obvious) **edit that clarified it, thanks**

Comment: Someone standing still on the floor? Is that any better?

Comment: If the ground is stationary and the airplane moves at $V$ with respect to the ground, then what exactly do you mean when you ask whether the aircraft is moving at "velocity $U+V$" when there's wind? We *started* by saying it moves at $V$ w.r.t. the ground, why would that change just because there's also wind moving relative to the ground?

Comment: Because surely the wind will make the plane move faster/slower?

Comment: @navop Also, just - to be sure  where do you get this from? `why the airs velocity can be treated as the planes velocity` ?  (i.e where do *something* or *someone* state this? book? person? website?)

Comment: Because from what I know you can only add the two velocities together to find the resultant velocity if they act on the same body

Comment: I think the it boils down to airspeed vs groundspeed in aviation. Airspeed is what the plane "feels" aireodynamically. Groundspeed is how fast you move in relation to the ground. You need groundspeed to calculate landing distances and travel times. You need airspeed to keep your plane from stalling or exceeding the maximum airframe speed.

Answer (score 1):

> Say we had an airplane cruising at velocity $V$

Velocity $V$ relative to what? Velocities are always *relative* to something.

If you mean that $V$ is the velocity of the plane *relative to the wind*, and $U$ is the velocity of the wind *relative to the ground*, then $V+U$ is indeed the velocity of the plane *relative to the ground*.

If $V$ is the velocity of the plane relative to the ground, then the velocity of the plane relative to the ground is $V$, not $V+U$. Then the velocity of the plane relative to the wind is $V-U$.

From an aerodynamic perspective, a plane is capable of a fixed velocity relative to the wind regardless of the speed of the wind. So with a tailwind a plane will indeed go faster relative to the ground than a plane with the same performance would with a headwind.

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: One more question, does the velocity of the plane change because the pilot changes the controls, or does the wind actually physically accelerate the plane?

Comment: @navop If the wind changes, the drag caused by the wind also changes. This can indeed decelerate the plane (more drag) or allow the engines to accelerate the plane (less drag). Assuming the change is gradual this involves no change in the plane's controls.

Comment: So how does it work when the wind is going in the same direction as the motion of the plane, do the air particles simply "push" the plane??

Comment: @navop No. Because the plane is moving faster than the wind (i.e. the wind *relative to the plane* is directed opposite to its direction of motion), it experiences aerodynamic drag. In cruise flight, this aerodynamic drag is in equilibrium with the other forces on the plane. If the wind speeds up, the relative speed of the wind decreases, which decreases the drag. Then the thrust of the engines can increase the speed of the plane until it reaches equilibrium again.

Comment: So even if the wind is going the same direction as the plane the plane experience drag?

Comment: @navop Yes, because the relative velocity of the wind needs to be in a certain direction for the plane to maintain lift. If the relative wind is coming from behind a plane, that plane will fall out of the air.

Answer (score -2):

As i understand your question the answer is **no**. [Wind velocity is not simply additive with the velocity of aerodynamic objects.](https://www.quora.com/How-does-wind-speed-affect-plane-speed) The same is true of intelligently operated sailboats, which [can indeed sail into the wind](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sailing_into_the_wind)